# The name `Foo` was already registered by another type, GraphQL

Tags: c#, graphql, mediatr

I am using GraphQL as a part of my CQRS application.
I have separated Command and Query domain model into two different projects (Query and Command).
each of there projects has some models for instance Student model.
I use two different model in `Domain.Query.Students.Student` and `Domain.Command.Students.Student`, but both have the same entity name (Student and Address)
I simplified my entity as below:

```
public class Student:Entity
{
    public  string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ModifiedOn { get; set; }
 }
```

Student is being used in Query and Command projects.
in `Startup.cs` I have configured GraphQL like this:

```
 services
 .AddGraphQLServer()
 .AddQueryType<StudentQuery>() 
 .AddMutationType<AddStudentMutation>();
```

In `StudentQuery.cs`

```
namespace GraphQL.Query.Students
{
    public class StudentQuery
    {
        
         
         public List<Student> AllStudents([ScopedService] StudentRepository studentRepository)
         {
             var query = studentRepository.GetEmployees();
             return query;
         }
    }
 }
```

and `AddStudentMutation.cs`

```
namespace GraphQL.Command.Students
{
    public class AddStudentMutation
    {
        public async Task<Student> AddStudentAsync(AddStudentInputType student,[Service] IMediator mediator)
        {
            var result =await mediator.Send(new AddStudentCommand(student.FirstName,student.LastName,student.StreetAddress,
                student.City,student.State,student.ZipCode));
            return result;
        }
    }
    
    [GraphQLName("AddStudentInput")]
    public class AddStudentInputType
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get;  set; }
        public string City { get;  set; }
        public string State { get;  set; }
        public string ZipCode { get;  set; }
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

```
The name `Student` was already registered by another type. (HotChocolate.Types.ObjectType<Domain.Query.Students.Student>)
```

If I change the Student entity in `Domain.Query.Students.Student` to ReadStudent or something else, it will run without any issue, but I don't want to change it.

Comment: I also faced a similar issue and by changing the name of the class it worked
It's a weird issue though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the GraphQL annotation onto the `Student` class as     `[GraphQLName("StudentQuery")]`

Comment: This works, but less than ideal if you want to keep your GraphQL layer separate from your model layer. We had to add a reference to `HotChocolate.Abstractions`...but it was still better than renaming the class just to make HC's schema loader happy.

Comment: yeah, perhaps the best if you introduce `AutoMapper Profile Instances` to configure the mapping with 
traversal attack awareness.